# Show addon tab panel in just the Compositor, not in Shader Editor

Tags: python, interface, add-on, compositing-nodes

How can I **only place the panel in the *compositor* NOT the *shader editor*** as doing `bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'` doesn't specify a specific node editor and places it in both?

Relevant code portion:

```py
class ExamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Node Compositing window"""
    bl_label = "MyTab"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_tab_pnl"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = "View"
    bl_category = "My Panel"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a poll function:

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    snode = context.space_data
    return snode.tree_type == 'CompositorNodeTree'
```